# Display series of numbers from lowest to highest

Tags: c#, bluej

I am taking a BlueJ (terminal for c#) class in high school and I have a programming practice problem that I can't figure out.

**Write a program that has the computer randomly choose three numbers from the range 1 to 50. Have the computer produce the output as shown.**

```
The first number chosen is 35
The second number chosen is 23
The third number chosen is 6

From lowest to highest: 6 23 35
```

The part I don't get is figuring out how display the variables in order from lowest to highest. I'm only supposed to use IF statements, no arrays or loops. (We aren't far enough in the course to use those)

Comment: Isn't BlueJ java, not C#?

Comment: There are only 6 possible permutations (ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA), so you should be able to determine which to print with a few nested `if` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can only use `if` or `else if`, then use the fact that there are six possible ways that three numbers can be permuted (FIRST = equals first number entered, SECOND = second number, THIRD = third number):

- FIRST SECOND THIRD
- FIRST THIRD SECOND
- SECOND FIRST THIRD
- SECOND THIRD FIRST
- THIRD FIRST SECOND
- THIRD SECOND FIRST

Because this is homework, I won't give you the code, but once you figure out the first line, it's trivial to do the other five. So, start by writing an `if` statement to capture the FIRST SECOND THIRD situation. (For example, if the user entered 5 10 15, in that order). Hint: use `<=` (less than or equals operator).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest grabbing a deck of cards it is great to think out problems like this and just talk your way through it.

If that doesn't fancy you and you just want an answer and not have to think about it, but this won't help you in the long run if you really want to learn.

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/sort.html